# Is there a way to create a blanket resolver for graphql queries, even if the type being resolved is a property to another type?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I'm building a GraphQL stitcher. My legacy GraphQL API lives in a rails app (server A). My new backend lives on server B and implements gRPC and not GraphQL. I'm building a gateway service (server C) that stitches the schema from server A and a local schema with resolvers that make gRPC requests to server B. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to use my new backend (server B) without changing my frontend code.

My current schema stitcher is the following

```js
import { stitchSchemas } from '@graphql-tools/stitch';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

import { RemoteSchemaFactory } from '~/main/services/remote-schema/remote-schema';
import { RemoteSchemaResult, SchemaConfig } from '~/types/graphql';
import { makeTypeDefs } from '~/main/graphql/type-defs';
import { makeResolvers } from '~/main/graphql/resolvers';

interface GatewaySchemaOptions {
  makeRemoteSchema: RemoteSchemaFactory;
  remoteSchemas: SchemaConfig[];
}

const localSchema = `
  type Organization {
    id: String!
    name: String
  }

  type Project {
    id: String!
    name: String
    organization: Organization
  }

  type Query {
    organization(id: String!): Organization
    project(id: String!): Project
  }
`;

export class GatewaySchema {
  schema: GraphQLSchema;
  remoteSchemas: SchemaConfig[];
  private factory: RemoteSchemaFactory;
  private localSchemas: GraphQLSchema[];

  constructor({ makeRemoteSchema, remoteSchemas }: GatewaySchemaOptions) {
    this.factory = makeRemoteSchema;
    this.remoteSchemas = remoteSchemas;
    const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: localSchema });
    this.localSchemas = [executableSchema];
  }

  async reload(schemas: GraphQLSchema[] = []): Promise<GraphQLSchema> {
    this.localSchemas = [...this.localSchemas, ...schemas];

    const remoteSchemas = await this.fetchRemoteSchemas();

    this.schema = await stitchSchemas({
      // The local schema MUST come first in the subschemas array
      subschemas: [
        ...this.localSchemas,
        ...remoteSchemas.map((item) => item.response),
      ],
      typeDefs: makeTypeDefs(),
      resolvers: makeResolvers({ k2Schema: this.localSchemas.at(0) }),
      onTypeConflict: (left, _right) => left,
    });

    return this.schema;
  }

  private async fetchRemoteSchemas(): Promise<RemoteSchemaResult[]> {
    return (
      await Promise.all(
        this.remoteSchemas.map(async ({ url, name, required }) => {
          const remoteSchema = this.factory(url, name);
          const response = await remoteSchema.build({ required });

          if (response)
            return {
              response,
              url,
              name,
            };
        }),
      )
    ).filter(Boolean);
  }
}
```

My resolver is the following

```js
import { IResolvers } from '@graphql-tools/utils';
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import { OrganizationServiceClient } from './client/organization.client';
import { GrpcTransport } from '@protobuf-ts/grpc-transport';
import { ChannelCredentials } from '@grpc/grpc-js';

export const makeOrganizationResolver = (
  schema?: GraphQLSchema,
): IResolvers => {
  if (!schema) throw TypeError(`missing required schema`);

  return {
    Query: {
      async organization(obj, args, context, info) {
        try {
          const transport = new GrpcTransport({
            host: 'localhost:9008',
            channelCredentials: ChannelCredentials.createInsecure(),
            // interceptors: [interceptor],
          });
          const client = new OrganizationServiceClient(transport);

          const result = await client.get({
            id: '5038828a-860f-4f51-8742-436ede3d542c',
          });

          console.log(result.response);
          return result.response.organization;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }

        return { id: 'org_id', name: 'Org name' };
      },
    },
  };
};
```

This successfully executes the following query by handling the organization resolver locally and calling the remote server for the project resolver.

```
query {
  project {
    id
  }
  organization {
    id
  }
}
```

However, my current stitcher/resolver implementation doesn't satisfy the following query document successfully. In the following query, it'll use the remote resolver to resolve the organization.

```
query {
  project {
    id
    organization {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to create a resolver in this local schema that will satisfy all queries where organization is a sub property to the requested type? I'm trying to avoid having to create n number of resolvers where n represents the number of entities that have organization as a child property.